# A library for interfacing TMS9918 with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to make a personal computer that includes using the ATMEGA8 acting as the CPU, and using an easy to interface DIP IC as video chip. I am considering to interface an Arduino with a TMS 9918 video chip,a chip used a lot in 1980s home computers, to an Arduino-this  seems like a good choice because it uses it own video RAM (instead of the Arduino's which cannot be expanded). 
So,my question is, where is the link to a library for interfacing the Arduino Uno  and TMS9918?

Comment: I just googled for it and didn't found any Arduino library for that chip. So I guess you need to write that yourself

Comment: what do you expect the finished project to be used for?